Visual Studio Doesn't Publish Modified Files With Unchanged Line Count
I have a large web project (Razor based) and I recently had to make changes to many files that DID NOT change the number of lines in those files.  When I did a publish, none of those files were published.  I have noticed before that you have to change the number of lines before it will recognize that those files have changed.
I've tried rebuilding the project to no avail.  Deleting the destination directory will work, but this is a large production code base and I do not want to do that.  The file properties have not been changed or set wrong.  I can manually publish each file individually, but I don't want to do that for so many.
Has anyone found a solution other than manually publishing each file?

Dependency of which files are compiled is based on the date and not the number of lines.  What changed between the original compile and the new compiled?  Did you update any libraries.  Dependency doesn't look at library changes so maybe that is when the files did not recompile.

I should clarify that I'm specifically speaking about .cshtml files that aren't compiled.

Do the file(s) get copies to the bin folder?  These type files should be placed in the main project folder.  Then in Solution Explorer right click on file and select Copy,  Then in Property box change the "Copy to Build folder" to "Copy if newer".   The file will be placed in the bin folder and then when publish will be part of the new release.

No.  The bin folder is only for DLLs and associated XML.

Where did you get the wrong info?  Any file can be placed in the bin folder and published.

Regarding the problem of Visual Studio 2022 not publishing files without changing the number of lines in the file, here are some possible solutions:
1: Build > Clean Solution > Rebuild Solution.
2: Use the MSBuild command-line tool to publish the project directly, which can bypass some limitations of Visual Studio:
msbuild /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=YourPublishProfil
3: Run this command in the project root directory, which will update the last modified time of all files:
powershell -command: Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ForEach-Object { $_.LastWriteTime = Get-Date }
4: If none of the above solutions work, please tell me what changed between your original compilation and the new compilation?


as stated, I tried this and it did not work; 2. I do not want to publish on each build; 3. definitely DO NOT want this; 4. conditions on a single line changed, so the line count of each file is the same.  note that these are non-compiled .cshtml files.


I wonder if your publishing method is to publish to a file system, or is it using the Web Deployment publishing method? If the publishing method is to publish to the file system, is "Delete all existing files prior to publish" checked in the "File publishing" settings?

This is a file system (or folder as it is now called) publish profile.  As I stated, I do not want to delete all files prior to publish as this is an old installation with an unknown number of desirable files there.
